# Loading Image from database using image path in Crystal report

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, model-view-controller, crystal-reports

I am trying to show employer's image in their detailed report. First of all I have taken a default image>Formate Object>Picture>Geografic Locaton> here I wrote "{EMPINFOS.ProfilePic}", column name. But it always shows the default image.
My image path sample in table: "/Image/EmployeePicture/EM_images_20190.jpg"

I have used dataset for report. My crystal report version in 13.0.21....
I have also tried to show image using parameter. results are following 
E:\Working\PMIS\PMIS\Image\EmployeePicture\EM_download_(1).jpg*********working
Image\EmployeePicture\EM_download_(1).jpg*********not working
\Image\EmployeePicture\EM_download_(1).jpg*********not working
~\Image\EmployeePicture\EM_download_(1).jpg*********not working

I just want to show the image. I think may b path is not correct. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You need full path and "\" instead of "/".  So use this expression:

```
"E:\Working\PMIS\PMIS" + Replace({EMPINFOS.ProfilePic}, "/", "\")
```

Comment: thanks. would you please tell me what to do when I publish it in hosting site? what to write in stead of "E:\Working\PMIS\PMIS".

Comment: You use whatever path the images are located at.

Comment: Yes. But I am setting the path in database. So when browsing from hosting site , it will not find E drive or Working folder there. As we use "~" for root folder in .net but  it is not correct for crystal report. So what can I use to define the root folder?